# max length of a string a char pointer can point to in C

Tags: c, json, blob

I believe I am hitting some boundary conditions, my requirement is to send some wifi scan report to mosquitto followed by Kibana

When I get wifi scan report in msg and try to convert that into a string as below

```
char *json = blobmsg_format_json(msg, true);

printf("json - %s and len - %ld", json, strlen(json));
```

this prints only 2048 characters in printf and strlen - ~28000

So my question is what is the max length of a constant string a char pointer can point to in C?
I am worried that `char *json` may not be pointing to complete string and what if I am getting only part of the string because of limitations?

More details:
I suspected above problem in question then I tried to declare another char pointer with malloc and then copy the string followed by terminating the string later to make sure its null terminated

```
/* 30000 Magic number I am using only for this example where I 
see that string len is not never greater than ~29000. This is 
just a debug and not will never make it to production */
char *tmpjson = (char *) calloc(30000,  sizeof(char)); 
strncpy(tmpjson, json, strlen(json));
strcat(tmpjson, "\"}");

printf("tmpjson - %s and len - %ld\n", tmpjson, strlen(tmpjson));
```

output is still the same as first printf except for terminating char

Comment: `what is the max length of a string a char pointer can point to in C` not relevant, I suspect X/Y problem. Do you know for sure that the returned value is null terminated?

Comment: I expect the number of characters printed and the string length are actually identical. Maybe parts of the string are unprintable control codes? Try sending the `printf()` output to a file or a utility like `xxd` and see what comes out.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, currently I am doing strcat on json string which takes care of null termination

Comment: *may not be pointing to complete string* -  a pointer points to the start address of a string.

Comment: The answer to your question does not solve your problem - you are asking an X-Y question.

Comment: You might include the output in your question, otherwise we have to take your word for it.  For example your code explicitly prints the string length, yet you have only said "~28000" whilst being very specific about the length of the output, which you would have had to count. That seems the wrong way around.

Comment: What compiler on what OS for what target are you using? It works for me (Win10, GCC 8.1.0).

Answer (score 3):

For your test code, you might be hit by an environmental limit: here is the relevant paragraph from the C Standard:

> **7.23.6.1 The `fprintf` function**
>
> [...]
>
> **Environmental limits**
> <sub>16</sub> The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least 4095.

Hence the implementation of `printf` might limit the number of characters printed from the `json` string to 4095, which makes this `printf` statement inappropriate for debugging your problem. In your observations, you only get 2048 characters, so either your library is seriously deficient or the way you collect the output and mesure its length is not working as expected.

The maximum size of a C string in only limited by available memory given by the operating system to your process with an absolute maximum at `SIZE_MAX`, which is at least `65535` and is the huge 64-bit number **18 446 744 073 709 551 615** on most current systems, so you are unlikely to hit this limit.

The function `blobmsg_format_json` might have its own limitations, which you can read in the documentation or determine from the source code.

Your second code fragment is incorrect: `strncpy` does not do what you expect, your code will have undefined behavior if the string pointed to by `json` has a length >= 30000. Learn why you should [never use `strncpy`](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/).

If you want to make allocate a copy of the string, use this:

```
char *tmpjson = strdup(json);
printf("tmpjson - %s and len - %zu\n", tmpjson, strlen(tmpjson));
```

But it should not come as a surprise that the result be identical.

To avoid `printf` limitations, use this:

```
printf("tmpjson - ");
fputs(json, stdout);
printf(" and len - %zu\n", strlen(json));
```

If the output is still too short, the problem definitely comes from the way you collect and measure the output.

The way you transmit the JSON data to the logging service is also something to investigate. Please post more details about that and your execution environment.

Answer (score 1):

The *pointer* refers the address of the *first element* of the string.  In that sense there is no limit on the length of string a pointer can refer to, because the *end* is not implied in the pointer value.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length is the maximum number representable by `size_t`, I believe, but this is guaranteed to be at least 16-bit and is 64-bit on my HP laptop. This is probably not your issue.